# What exception should I throw in java when I detect something is wrong?

Tags: java

Let's say I have a text file which stores names of students and another text file which stores their grades and I am trying to consolidate these into one text file (or could be doing some other processing). Further lets say I write a class which provides an iterator that basically abstracts away the fact that the data is stored in two separate files. This iterator would have methods like so:

```
public class MyIterator
{
   public boolean hasNext()
   {
       boolean a = this.nameReader.hasNext();
       boolean b = this.gradeReader.hasNext();
       if (a != b)
       {
          // the number of records in the two files don't match; 
          // most likely input is wrong and user should be alerted about it
          // **Question: What exception should I throw here?**
       }
       return a;
   }

   public MyTuple next()
   {
       // read the next records from both files and
       // combine them into a tuple 
   }
}
```

Java has [`IllegalStateException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) but its description doesn't match the problem here.

[`IllegalStateException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) :
Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation.

Comment: The standard one is `IllegalArgumentException` but in this case maybe you want to define your own, because you'll probably handle it separately from all other problems.

Comment: Unless there's an `IncorrectFileArgumentException` you should create yours

Comment: As you are storing data in a file..may be you can throw `EOFException`

Comment: You sure you want to use an exception? Here's an interesting blog about exceptions by Eric Lippert that suggests that may be a bad idea: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx. It is geared more toward C# but the two languages are very similar.

Comment: You probably wanna make your own and make it unchecked (extend RuntimeException) like ```IllegalArgumentException``` so that it bubbles up the stack without the need for handling it anywhere.

Comment: Does the program's user have a chance to fix the problem? - Also, running the program with 99% output and *then* throw an exception isn't a good strategy. This kind of data error should be signalled prior to any processing.

Comment: I don't think that `IllegalArgumentException` is a good choice: there is no argument being passed to `hasNext` to be illegal. I would go for `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: @laune your point is well taken. Lets say the ctor of the class has an overload with a boolean argument which dictates whether this kind of validation should be done before using the class. A user who is more focussed on performance would set the boolean to false. Thus, lets stick to the OP please and I am interested in knowing what is the most appropriate native java exception I should throw.

Comment: @morpheus What would user do when he sees that exception (or a decent error message derived from it) or do you want to catch and handle programmatically? - As it stands, I'm for Ill.StateEx. with a message telling user what is wrong: "mismatching data files - check program parameters" or the like. - Note: many users are shocked by a Java stack trace and the lingo - but I'm sure you know that.

Comment: Yes, IllegalStateException seems to be the best choice and that is what I am using.

Answer (score 0):

`IllegalArgumentException` is a good exception to throw, but if it doesn't meet your needs, you could always create your own exception.  Remember, you don't always want to display the results of your exception to the public so you may want to handle that exception in a different way while logging the results of your exception.

Comment: *"`IllegalArgumentException` is a good exception to throw"* And why do you think that a method without parameters should throw an `IllegalArgumentException`?

Comment: Consider changing it for IllegalStateException, i think it's more close to invalid state, _the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html)  for IllegalStateException says_: Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, the Java environment or Java application **is not in an appropriate state** for the requested operation

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are implementing an interface's method, and that method does not throw any checked exceptions, you are limited only to subclasses of `RuntimeException`.

If none of the existing subclasses fits your situation, you can always create your own, though this is usually less recommended for unchecked execeptions (as they don't automatically appear in the JavaDoc). It's important to document whatever it is you are throwing in the JavaDoc for your class.

If I'm asked to pick an existing runtime exception for the situation you have described, I might choose [`UncheckedIOException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/UncheckedIOException.html) wrapped around an [`EOFException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html).

Comment: I am not implementing any interface. Should I still use unchecked exception?

Comment: I thought you were implementing the `Iterator` interface. You should be if you are making an "iterator-like" class. But if you are not implementing it, you should probably use checked exceptions as they are more well-documented.